# SQL Server how to retrieve all numbers between 2 numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 4 columns- Code, Amount, Start, End. I would like to take the between amounts in the start and end columns and change them into one column with all results. Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Thanks.

```
Current Results:
Code  Amount  Start  End
1     5000    2015   2016
2     5000    2014   2016
3     20000   2012   2016

Desired Results:
Code  Amount  StartEnd
1     5000    2015
1     5000    2016
2     5000    2014
2     5000    2015
2     5000    2016
3     20000   2012
3     20000   2013
3     20000   2014
3     20000   2015
3     20000   2016
```

Comment: which version of sql server?

Comment: Sorry, it's 2008.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a recursive cte to generate all the numbers between minimum start and maximum end and join on the generated numbers.

```
with cte as (select min(start) col,max(end) mx from tablename
             union all
             select col+1,mx from cte where col < mx)
select t.code,t.amount,c.col
from cte c
join tablename t on c.col between t.start and t.end
```

or more simply

```
with cte as (select id,amount,start startend,end from tablename
             union all
             select id,amount,start+1,end from cte where start<end)
select id,amount,startend
from cte
order by 1,3
```

Comment: maybe I'm wrong...   left join means if there are years without values there will be a row with only the last column and nulls so I guess it up to the op

Comment: @Hogan .. left join not required here.

Comment: right, unless he wants to show years that don't have any ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a UDF.  I use this TVF to generate dynamic ranges

```
Declare @YourTable table (Code  int, Amount int,  Start int , [End] int)
Insert into @YourTable values 
(1,5000 ,2015,2016),
(2,5000 ,2014,2016),
(3,20000,2012,2016)

Select A.Code
      ,A.Amount
      ,StartEnd = cast(B.RetVal as int)
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Number](A.Start,A.[End],1)) B
```

Returns

```
Code    Amount  StartEnd
1       5000    2015
1       5000    2016
2       5000    2014
2       5000    2015
2       5000    2016
3       20000   2012
3       20000   2013
3       20000   2014
3       20000   2015
3       20000   2016
```

The Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Number] (@R1 money,@R2 money,@Incr money)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M) As (Select cast((@R2-@R1)/@Incr as int)),
         cte1(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N) As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d,cte1 e,cte1 f,cte1 g,cte1 h )

    Select RetSeq=1,RetVal=@R1 Union All Select N+1,(N*@Incr)+@R1
    From   cte2   
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- 
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Number](0,4,0.25)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query like this

```
SELECT
    c.code,
    c.amount,
    f.yr
FROM #code c
CROSS APPLY fn_yearslist(c.startyr, c.endyr) f
```

function you cancreate like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_yearslist (@startyear int, @endyear int)
RETURNS @t TABLE (
    yr int
)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE (@startyear <= @endyear)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @t (yr)
        VALUES (@startyear)
    SET @startyear += 1
    END
    RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it works on SQL 2008, but here's a CTE:

```
;with sel_cte as (
select Code, Amount, start StartEnd
from @tblTest t

union all

select t.code, t.amount, c.StartEnd + 1 StartEnd
from sel_cte c
  inner join @tblTest t on t.code = c.code
where c.StartEnd + 1 <= [end]
)
select *
from sel_cte
order by Code, StartEnd
```

Note: replace @tblTest with the actual table name.

Answer (score -1):

If the requirements allow you to ONLY have successive numbers (like 2014, 2015, then 2016, etc) then the approach above (cte) would work fine. However, if not, you could create a another temp table (say numbers having 1 column) with numbers in successive sequence of what all you want to be the result output, like.

```
Number
2014
2015
2016
2018 <-- Missing 2017 and jumping on 2018
2019
```

And then use a right join to get results in the progressive series with a query similar to the one below.

```
select Code, StartEnd, Amount from numbers 
    right join inputs on number between Start and End
```

Comment: I am failing to see a couple of things 1) how is this relevant to the question the OP has clearly stated "retrieve all numbers between 2 numbers" indicating successive numbers. 2) you mentioned you can populate another temp table if you want but you don't show any method of how to do that or discuss logic of it.  Perhaps you are believing that the cte method will take the MAX & MIN of the table and generate all the numbers.  So if there is break lets say row 3 where start 2009 end 2012 then you would be missing data for 2013?  But the cte can actually ignore 2013 as well

Comment: the approach of another table could introduce the additional flexibility of skipping numbers, may be, for future. i missed the details of creating and inserting a single-col table with the assumption that the single-col table with successive numbers should be easy to create and populate. Also, with cte approach ignoring or skipping a number would require hard-coding. Sorry, but i am coming from a full-stack background to have all these thoughts inherent.